# Wild Card Search - Dynamic SOQL

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I'm building dynamic SOQL based on the User Input from UI.

I'm looking to build a wild card input search.
For Example,

1. if user enters `"Apple*"`, query should return all records that start with "Apple" for that field.
2. if user enters `"*Apple*"`, query returns all records where field contains "Apple"

I've a dynamic query with LIKE '%Apple%' operator, but when "*" is entered, its treating it as value and no results returned. I want to know a way to process positioning of * and than dynamically create soql accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this would just be a simple replacement in apex like so:

```
String s = '*Apple*'.replace('*', '%');
s = s;
```